# how to display data on combo box in edit form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, combobox

i choose a data from combo box on insert form and stored in database ..
then i want to display that data on edit form but if i want to change the data i can choose from combo box again..can you help me? thank you

this code on my edit form:

```
<select class="select" name="category">
<option>Choose Category</option>

<?php
require_once './db_freelancer.php';
$get_data = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from project_category");
while($category = mysqli_fetch_array($get_data)){

echo "  <option value=".$category['category_id'].">".$category['category_name']."</option>";
}
?>

</select>
```

Comment: You need the category that was previously saved to be able to set `selected` on the appropriate `<option>`

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code....Edit this code as per your data structure

```
$member_category = $memberdata['category_id']; // Retrieve member's category from database.


<select class="select" name="category">
<option>Choose Category</option>

<?php
   require_once './db_freelancer.php';
   $get_data = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from project_category");
      while($category = mysqli_fetch_array($get_data)){

 echo '<option value="'.$category['category_id'].'" '.(($category['category_id']==''.$member_category.'')?'selected="selected"':"").'>'.$category['category_name'].'</option>';
  } ?>

 </select>
```